# get the value of checkbox selected row

Tags: jquery, datatables

I am getting the value of checkbox by doing this

```
$('input:checked', oTable.fnGetNodes()).each(function(i){

            console.log(this);

        });
```

it gives me

```
<input type="checkbox" class="datatableCheckbox">
```

but how do I get the other values in the other columns of data table in same row??

thanks

Comment: It's been awhile since I used datatables but can't you access the parent cell then the parent row and traverse?

Comment: Post the full HTML from one of the `tr` elements this `checkbox` is in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *how do I get the other values in the other columns of data table in same row??*

Assuming you are dealing with a HTML table, then you can simply get the closest `tr` and find the respective `td`'s

```
$('input:checked', oTable.fnGetNodes()).each(function(i){
    console.log($(this)
       .closest('tr') //get the enclosing tr
       .find('td:eq(1)'));  //find any using td:eq(<index>)
});
```

Comment: this wont work in chrome and internet explorer it got the opposite reaction in which when a checkbox is check it says that it is unchecked and when it is unchecked it sets as check its totally weird

Comment: @RobertDeanPantino Would you be able to post a small demo where I can take a look. I am sure this is not a browser issue..

Answer (score 0):

Try this inside your loop:

```
$(this).closest('tr').find('input[type="checkbox"]').each(function(i, checkbox){
    console.log($(checkbox).val());
});
```

Or if you want values from all form elements:

```
$(this).closest('tr').find(':input').each(function(i, input){
    console.log($(input).val());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$(oTable.fnGetNodes()).find('td').each(function(i){

      console.log(this);  // This will give you the td for each row..

});
```

Assuming `oTable.fnGetNodes()` returns the **tr's** in the table